# Change the default text-based color codes to custom HEX in stylesheet

Tags: css

Is it possible to define the default text color codes in a stylesheet

For example: I use this color all over my site, I hate typing it. color:#27408B;

Instead what I want to do is define the default text blue to be color:#27408B;

so I can just type border:1px solid blue; and it will come out border:1px solid #27408B;

Comment: With plain CSS no, you can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do can be accomplished by using a CSS Pre-processor. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), and [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) are some of the more notable ones out there. Pre-processors allow you to create variables, mixins, functions, and more to help streamline your work.

To create a variable, all you'll need to do is declare it in your stylesheet accordingly:

```
@blue = "#27408b"
```

In the example above, **@blue** is the name of the new variable, whereas the value between the quotations is the true value for **@blue** henceforth.

```
body {background: @blue;} /* your background will be the color #27408b */
a {color: @blue;} /* your link will be the color #27408b */
div {border: 1px solid @blue;} /* your 1px border will be the color #27408b */
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use preprocessors like:

> LESS: http://lesscss.org/

or

> Sass: http://sass-lang.com/

For example in LESS you can do this:

```
@color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
  color: @color;
}
```